# Can CM pings show up the same way annotations do?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools

It's really useful to know if a CM ping has already been sent out for a user. Currently, you have to dig around in the user's history to find out if this has happened, and to read the message.

Can CM pings go in the same place annotations and suspensions do on `/history`? Can they also increment the counter on the user profile?

[image]

If pings automatically created an annotation, that would be fine too.

Comment: This is reasonable, and likely to happen when we start improving this tool.

Comment: @Jnat \**Checks JNat vs jmac** ... Thanks interbrain!

Comment: @JNat it would be especially useful if a link there showed both the mod text and the CM response, like with the other type of dialogue that shows up there.  That'd simplify communication compared to how the CM responses are transmitted now.

Comment: Not sure how we're gonna go about doing that yet, but that is one of the things we are taking into consideration, @MonicaCellio.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is being rolled out now. Escalations to the Community Team will now have a section of their own in the user history page, separated from the annotations/suspensions section:

[image: User history page]

You may have noticed they're now clickable too: that's 'cause [now you can see the Community Team's replies back to you](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/285899/208518). Aside from this, they continue to create entries on the user history list, as they used to do.

Beside the annotations and post flags counts, we now also have a separate counter for messages to the community team:

[image: Counter]