# Oh CMs Where art thou?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange, community

I've been waffling a bit about bringing this up - but what are the plans/status on the new CM hires that were mentioned in the post about [SE raising funds](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/351385/135565)?

There's [certainly demand](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353982/we-expect-some-q3-projects-to-be-delayed) for their services, and something more than a skeleton team will likely allow for better interactions and insight into the community, since well, frankly, in hindsight - the period in which communities were basically left to fend for themselves in complete benign neglect hasn't worked that well. I'm reminded of a story of  how manufacturers would remove components from a device till it fails, then add back the last thing they removed. You *could* add it back, but it isn't quite right, and the magic smoke could escape again.

It's a role I have been historically (and currently) interested in and to a small extent, it feels selfish to ask but... someone had to. While the PM roles [have been open](https://stackoverflow.com/company/work-here) since pretty much immediately after Prashanth's post. We've also had, in the meanwhile, openings for Director and even Vice President roles - which I'm sure are vitally important as well

What I haven't seen are community roles. I'm a little baffled (and mildly impatient) over the lack of movement over what should be essential ground level hires.

Promises kept are important. They express a commitment. But just as much, promises do need to be kept in somewhat of a timely manner.

Almost two months on the original post, and as someone who is keenly interested in giving the role one last shot (and If I don't get it, looking forward to working with future CMs as a mod much as I have over the last few years) - what's the plan and status on the new hires, and when are we going to see the openings, and hopefully a revitalised community team?

---

I suspect now that *a* job ad is up, this is a *conditionally* [status-complete](/questions/tagged/status-complete) issue.- You can find further thoughts on the subject [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355681/135565)

Comment: Iiiiiiiii am a CM of constant sorrow, I've seen troubles all my days. Iiiiiiiii bid farewell to moderating, the place that I learned all my trade.

Comment: The place that she learned all her trade!

Comment: *Oh CMs, wherefore are [ye](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ye_(pronoun)) silent?* Little known fact: the form "art thou" is the archaic 2nd person singular, as in "O brother, where art thou?"

Comment: @Mari-LouA I was thinking of something a little more contemporary for a reference. I didn't expect the impromptu flik :D

Comment: To note, with the mod agreement signature end date near, I still think that unfortunatly the SE leadership will sink the last free time our CM got right now (if they got any?), as it mean a lot of sites might need elections and attentions.

Comment: Job ads can be up for weeks, months even. Having an ad up doesn't change the status IMO. But it's a good start :-)

Comment: *conditionally* As such. I hope to not have to follow up :D

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This question is very relevant to my life right now as my last meeting yesterday was finalizing the job description with Teresa and getting feedback on the interview plan. I understand from the outside that it may look like nothing is happening, but we’ve been working on this internally since the ink was dry on the fundraising docs.

Some of the jobs you’ve seen posted already were being worked on before we raised capital. I’m talking specifically about the PM role on the Public Platform team and the VP of Product Engineering role.

To give some insight into the hiring process post fundraise, step 1 was for the Senior Leadership to meet with their Directors and Managers and discuss team needs. They then brought back an 18 month hiring plan to discuss with the rest of leadership and establish operating budgets. That process is ongoing through the end of the month for the 18 month hiring plan, across the company new hires are being planned for and hiring plans are being worked on.  However, I'm happy to share that we just got confirmation for an early recruiting approval which we requested.

You can expect the job posting to go up over the next few weeks. This is one of the few things I’m not cancelling meetings for during [the Ticket Smash](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/353982) as it’s super important.

Comment: Fingers crossed on improvements to the job description! 

Comment: If you weren't working on this until the company raised capital does that mean that there was no intention to replace the two fired CMs and the one who quit? Because those positions were already in the budget, right?

Comment: @curiousdannii we didn't have open CM positions before the fundraise.

Comment: @SaraChipps Yes. But what possible reason could you have to not replace three essential roles? And why was fundraising needed when the positions were previously accounted for in the budget? I assume you or others would say those positions weren't essential. *That's the problem.*

Comment: Like many companies who experienced the down market because of the pandemic, we were constrained financially. We lost some amazing teammates, it was not an easy time.

Comment: @SaraChipps It was early January when the 3 CMs were lost. This year has been a very difficult year for many people, but there was time to at least advertise for CMs before the economy crashed on Feb 20. What was happening in those six weeks?

Comment: @curiousdannii Cutting before the end of year, or start of fiscal year is simply to balance a budget sadly. The crux there IMO is with the last year problem(s), some communities are in cruise control, and the return of the last year action will become apparant soon with moderator(s) that will just not sign the new agreement as they are burn, but silent. And the SE leadership cutted CM position. I really dont understand their moves.

Comment: Listing looks pretty solid; major improvement from last year. Still some gate-keeping bs, but that's par for the course.