# Oh CMs where art thou? (Reprise)

Tags: discussion, community

It's been somewhere [close to 6 months](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354203/oh-cms-where-art-thou) since I last asked about this, though I've alluded to [aspects of this in my response to the latest roadmap](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/360222/mse-feedback-post-feedback-on-q1-2021-community-and-public-platform-roadmap/360257?noredirect=1#comment1202251_360257).

We're hearing a lot of grand plans of eventually having specialised Community teams.

How *are* things going with hiring new CMs? I don't see a job ad out now, so I assume that at least the first round of hiring out to be deep in the pipeline. I've heard hints of at least one CM-adjacent hire who I've not seen around yet.

How many can we expect to see, and is there any roadmap/plans on the eventual growth and make up of the broader CM team that can be shared?

Comment: From the [blog post published a few days ago](https://stackoverflow.blog/2021/01/28/the-loop-community-public-platform-roadmap-q1-2021/): *our first CM hire starts on Feb 1*

Comment: [Shodipo Ayomide](https://stackexchange.com/users/8194929/shodipo-ayomide?tab=accounts), [Tavern Chat](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/8727928#8727928) - Conversation between you and Catija, a week ago.

Comment: I might have missed the exact date - but ya, that's the one CM-adjacent hire (since he did describe himself as a developer relations manager - and I'm unsure where that fits in. I kept this vague cause I really want to see what the company has to say, if they can.

Comment: It is odd that with all the people in the world that it takes several months to hire one person; so I'm with you on "Why?", or how does that happen.

Comment: It's not somewhat six months, it's just over 3 months.  I hope you get that long awaited call.

Comment: Ah, I'm don't think I'm in this round of hires. I'd be making a fuss over many of these things *internally* if I was, and I certainly wouldn't want to post this if I felt like I was lobbying for myself.  Also "asked Sep 14 '20 at 23:06" ... Math isn't my strong point but that feels closer to 5 than 4 and...

Comment: Ahh, I was looking at the time stamp. My bad.

Comment: What are the chances that this gets asked 1 day before the first new CM was scheduled to start?

Comment: Entirely random.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Our first CM hire ([Shodipo Ayomide](https://stackexchange.com/users/8194929/shodipo-ayomide?tab=accounts)) [started on February 16](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360990/51).

We have received a large number of applications for the other open CM positions - the listing for the position has been taken down while we catch up on the back log, and will be opened again when it is relevant.

> …eventually having specialised Community teams

This is not an eventuality. The transition to these teams is underway right now.

Comment: It's great to know Shodipo will be starting tomorrow. Also, you wrote "We have received a large number of applications for the other open CM positions ...". How many other current open CM positions are there?

Comment: As discussed in quite a few places - I see it as an eventuality, cause for specialisation to be effective, you're going to need enough people, get them trained on what they lack and so on. Practically - if everything went well, I see it as a multi month  project to start with *even with* a fully staffed team, which y'all lack right now.  I might have some degree of impatience to see stuff working as well :D

Comment: Um, they don't seem to have started doing anything, and still don't have their staff privileges yet...what happened?

Comment: @SonictheCuriouserHedgehog had some logistical issues that have been sorted. Please [welcome Ayo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/360990/51)

Comment: As said elsewhere about damn time 

Comment: @YaakovEllis are there plans to make more hires in the near future?

Comment: @Luuklag yes, definitely

Comment: Good to know @YaakovEllis. I hope the workload can be eased for you guys with some extra hires.

Comment: Well - while the specific CM is no longer with the company, with multiple openings and hires the issue is for, all intents and purposes, resolved I guess. I'll select this, pending any more precise answer, just to close the loop