# Does Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange use Jira Service Management?

Tags: support, email, company

I contacted Stack Overflow a month ago using the contact page.

I received a mail on 23<sup>rd</sup> July, 2021 from jira@stackoverflow.atlassian.net. Here's the screenshot of the email:

[image: Screenshot of email]

I was confused if this was an official email from Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange or spam email as the "from" email address was not having a Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange domain. Does Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange use Jira Service Management?

I hope a Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange employee will be able to give a confirmatory answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, we have used Jira for over a year now. Unfortunately, one of the downsides of Jira is that they do not allow using your own email servers or email address for outgoing email. All outgoing email from our projects does go through that address.

Comment: Is it mandatory for users to sign-up in https://stackoverflow.atlassian.net to be able to communicate with SE/SO staff?

Comment: No it is not. Which is why we have the notification turned off for the Public Q&A project - it just causes confusion and weirdness. I'm not sure why you were added in the Technical Support project (which is only for Teams/Talent).

Comment: I think Philippe might know the reason why I was added in the Technical Support project.

Comment: @RandomPerson - almost definitely a result of me digging and finding your old ticket and assigning it to someone on my team. :)

Comment: (As a note, we still use Jira for issue tracking internally, but no longer use it as a support portal.)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, they use Jira for ticket management. Here are some recent mentions by staff:

> Last but not least, Sara oversaw and facilitated the adoption of many great things for this team, such as projects, retros, a move to Jira

([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/364384/295232))

> Over the course of two weeks we have handled around 500 tickets (all tickets in Freshdesk and Jira). We still have some tricky ones in Trello but overall we dropped the “day-to-day” ticket queue to zero.

([source](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/355014/295232))

Staff will be able to confirm that they use that specific email address, but you know it's the weekend, don't you? :)